# Appending variables and double quotes in csh

Tags: string, append, csh

I have

```
set a = 'foo'
set b= 'string'
set b = "${b} = \"${a}\""
echo $b
```

and I would like the output to be `string = "foo"`

Can this be done on one line to escape the double quote inside a double quoted assignment? I know you cannot escape double quotes with `\` so is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set a="foo"
set b='string'
set b="${b} = "\""${foo}"\"
echo ${b}
```

*edit for syntax*

Comment: that would work, but I forgot my real code needs to append itself to another variable and `"`. When I try that I get `set: Variable name must begin with a letter.` but when I don't have `${b}` on the right side it will work fine.